# Return node after aggregation in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am having a hard time understanding how to properly use aggregate functions in Cypher.

Let say I have nodes labelled as `Animal`, with properties `size` and `species`.
For each species, I want to get the largest.

So far, I understand I can do it with the following :

```
MATCH (n:Animal)
WITH n.species as species, max(n.size) as size
RETURN species, size
```

And I will effectively get the largest sizes with corresponding species.

But how can I get the nodes instead of species ?

I can't return `n` because of the `WITH` statement, and I can't inject it into the `WITH` because it will break `species` aggregation.

I know this question has already been asked a few times, but the different solutions I came accross were case-specific and used relations

Any advice is very welcome

EDIT: I finally made it work with :

```
MATCH (n:Animal)
WITH n.species as species, max(n.size) as size, collect(n) as ns
UNWIND ns as n
WITH n
WHERE n.size = size
RETURN n
```

Is this the Cypher-way to settle things ? Seems a bit verbose and not efficient (all nodes are fetched here) to me, isn't there a more straightforward option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `MAX` aggregation function does not return the *node* with the max value, you should not use it. Otherwise, you'd have to test the size of every animal *twice* to get both the max value and the node of interest (as you discovered).

You can instead use the `REDUCE` function to test the size of every animal just once:

```
MATCH (n:Animal)
WITH n.species AS species, COLLECT(n) as ns
RETURN species, REDUCE(s = {size: -1}, a IN ns |
  CASE WHEN a.size > s.size THEN {size: a.size, a: a} ELSE s END
) AS result;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a frequently encountered limitation with our max() and min() aggregation functions, so we added an [APOC function](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/overview/) that can help: `apoc.agg.maxItems()`:

> apoc.agg.maxItems(item, value, groupLimit: -1) - returns a map {items:[], value:n} where `value` is the maximum value present, and `items` are all items with the same value. The number of items can be optionally limited.

```
MATCH (n:Animal)
WITH n.species as species, apoc.agg.maxItems(n.size, n) as sizeData
RETURN species, sizeData.value as size, sizeData.items as animals
```